# My documents in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, mapped-folder

Is there a way of having " my documents" ( folder on my machine) folder mapped to a folder in SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map network drives to Sharepoint document libraries with [webdav](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-webdav-network-drive.html) or with "typical" drive mapping.\spurl\sites\sitecollection\DocLibraryName